# WebPack 4.29 and html-loader 2.1.4 loading modularized html files

Tags: html, webpack

I've got an issue trying to use WebPack and html-loader to modularize my html files (eg. have an index.html as the template, and load in components to that such as header.html). If anyone can shed any light that would be great!

WebPack Config:
---rest omitted

```
  {
    test: /\.(html)$/,
    use: {
      loader: 'html-loader',
      options: {
        interpolate: true,
      },
    },
  },
```

Example import in index.html:

```
<div>
  ${require(‘./header.html’)}
</div>
```

Any more details please don't hesitate to ask!